# How to replace all nil value with "" in a ruby hash recursively?

Tags: ruby, hash, proc

```
str = "<a><b><c></c></b></a>"
hash = Hash.from_xml(str)
# => {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>nil}}}
```

How can I replace all `nil`s in a Hash to `""` so that the hash becomes:

```
{"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>""}}}
```

Comment: Are keys always a string? What are possible values?

Comment: @sawa Keys are legal Hash keys. Only `nil` value should be altered.

Comment: Any object is a legal hash key. You already wrote in the question that only nil should be altered.

Comment: I believe the idea is that keys are not changed, that values equal to `nil` are to be changed to equal an empty string.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a recursive method that does not change the original hash.

**Code**

```
def denilize(h)
  h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g|
    g[k] = (Hash === v) ?  denilize(v) : v.nil? ? '' : v }
end
```

**Examples**

```
h = { "a"=>{ "b"=>{ "c"=>nil } } }
denilize(h) #=> { "a"=>{ "b"=>{ "c"=>"" } } }

h = { "a"=>{ "b"=>{ "c"=>nil , "d"=>3, "e"=>nil}, "f"=>nil  } }
denilize(h) #=> { "a"=>{ "b"=>{ "c"=>"" , "d"=>3, "e"=>""}, "f"=>"" } }
```

Answer (score 2):

this will destroy the original hash and will not work with hashes with infinite recursion.

```
def nil2empty(hash)
  hash.keys.each do |key|
    if hash[key].kind_of? Hash
      nil2empty(hash[key])
    else
      hash[key] = '' if hash[key].nil?
    end
  end
  true # of course, what else? :P
end
```

example of usage:

```
hash
 => {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>nil}}} 
nil2empty(hash)
 => true 
hash
 => {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>""}}}
```

Comment: Since your method destroys the original hash, the appropriate method name would be `nil2empty!` via Ruby convention. Rather, if we were to go even more into convention, the method name would be `nil_to_empty!` and it would return `nil`.

Comment: @David the bang methods convention destroy the caller object. nil2empty is not a method on the Hash model and it don't change the called (which I don't even know who is), I think is for the best leave without the bang. Also, accordingly to [this style guide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby) (which is the one I usually use) the bangs method should only exist if there is a non-bang method as well.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. Would probably be appropriate to monkey-patch something like this into `Hash` though... wherein if one did that my conventions would apply :P.

Comment: To avoid destroying the original hash you could of course first make a deep copy.  One way is with [Marshal#dump](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Marshal.html#method-c-dump) and [Marshal#load](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Marshal.html#method-c-load): `hash_copy = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(hash))`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer you are expecting, but if you  could handle a value instead of "" , this code works

```
eval({"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>nil}}}.to_s.gsub("nil", "1")) #=> returns a hash #{"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>1}}}
```